# Webview not working?

Tags: android, xml

I've got the following method...

```
public class Image extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

/* Using WebView to display the full-screen image */
WebView full = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

/* Set up the Zoom controls */
FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
final View zoom = this.full.getZoomControls();
mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

/* Create a new Html that contains the full-screen image */
String html = new String();
html = ("<html><center><img src=\"1276253554007.jpg\"></html>" );

/* Finally, display the content using WebView */
full.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/",
                                                        html,
                                                        "text/html",
                                                        "utf-8",
                                                        "");
}

}
```

R.id.webview refrences...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

But I'm getting a `full cannot be resolved or is not a field` compile error, but full is defined as.. `WebView full = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);` anyone have any idea why this isnt working?

Thanks.

Comment: is that in the "onCreate"? if it cant find it, then you are in the wrong "context". can you post the entire code for the method? like where the content view is set, etc.

Comment: To what ZOOM_PARAMS variable refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "this." prefix from the full variable usages.
It looks like you're trying to access method local variable, while "this." keyword is intended  for accessing member variables.

Here is modified code sample which compiled and runs just fine for me.

```
    public class Image extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    /* Using WebView to display the full-screen image */
    WebView full = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    /* Set up the Zoom controls */
    FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = full.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    /* Create a new Html that contains the full-screen image */
    String html = new String();
    html = ("<html><center><img src=\"1276253554007.jpg\"></html>" );

    /* Finally, display the content using WebView */
    full.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/",
                                                            html,
                                                            "text/html",
                                                            "utf-8",
                                                            "");
    }

}
```

Comment: .. or change `WebView full = ` to `full = ` if you want to initialize a member variable and access it later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments to the other answer reminded me of a [similiar problem I once read on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999855/android-custom-dialog-nullpointerexception/3000515#3000515). Guess it's the same: you're looking for `WebView` in the Actitvity view while I guess it's actually declared in a dialog view... The linked answer solved the other OP's problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand how I'd apply that solution to my problem, perhaps you could explain a little more?